# Configure style of auto-drawn bounding box/selection outlines

Tags: paperjs

I want to increase the stroke width of bounding rectangle in paperjs. Is that even possible?

Here is my code:

```
var circlePath = new Path.Ellipse(new Point(50, 50), 50);
circlePath.style = {
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 5
};

circlePath.bounds.strokeWidth = 10;
circlePath.bounds.selected = true;
```

Here, I am trying to do `circlePath.bounds.strokeWidth = 10`, but it is not working. Here is the [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/fVA9D4IwEP0rTRcwIQQGFoiTcTdxcBCHUs7QcLakPSSG8N+lGCIuDne5u/fefY1ciwfwnJ9bINnwiEtT+7y0pV7tKSyTykqEk6CG7ZmGgfkwPiKqzkG4FIzSFGZJxLJkt7jCi7/C2NELYZaPS2O6K8SDQWNzFgyNIgiiD+DImhZWqEIh21/oompqcpYmvjgV656bUZXpde3iDX2emyb/qIAgCeqZR7aHYn5FZUG0nT/L8fx6m94=) link.

Also, `bounds` only shows the 4 corner points. But here in the documentation, I can see 6 points. How can I show 6 points in my case?

[Documentation](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/transforming-items/#the-bounding-rectangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection outlines are not that much configurable in PaperJS, although there are [open issues for this feature](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/433).

However it's relatively easy to write up our own method on `Item` that draws a custom bounding box.

Here's some sample code:

```js
paper.setup(document.querySelector('canvas'))

paper.Item.prototype.select = function(selected = true) {
  // Hide PaperJS selection outlines since we draw our own.
  this.selectedColor = new paper.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
  this.selected = selected
 
  if (!selected) return this.bbox.remove()

  this.bbox = new paper.Group({
    // lock this so it doesn't respond to mouse events etc..
    locked: true,
    children: [
      // add the bbox...
      new paper.Path.Rectangle({
        rectangle: this.strokeBounds,
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 4
      })
    ]
  })
  
  // ... and the handles.
  ;[
    'topLeft',
    'topCenter',
    'topRight',
    'leftCenter',
    'bottomLeft',
    'bottomRight',
    'bottomCenter',
    'rightCenter'
  ].forEach(pos => {
    this.bbox.addChild(new paper.Path.Circle({ 
      position: this.bounds[pos], 
      radius: 5, 
      fillColor: 'blue' 
    }))
  })
}

// ... and use it like this.

const circle = new paper.Path.Circle(new paper.Point(100, 70), 50)
circle.fillColor = 'black'

circle.select(true)
```

```css
canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>

<canvas resize></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate to have a rectangle as a bounding box. See [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/XZA/j8IwDMW/SpSlRaqqMrC0YjrdjrjhhoMhTQyNahLkmEMI8d1JihCBIX/8fnr2k6/SqQPIVv6MwHqQldTepHpDG/c8/4qEtqQRVooHsRQOziJ9629EewxQToK3jstFU4lFM5uuLplfxjrwBSHar1Nj3lnEL4+eWlGcB8tQVA8QmPwIT9Sj0uM7+rWGh1bMmyTeujwngeY84TrWyu0RyixI70/OhEe+ZKizidFcEJjiE04zI5w3GQGMD5goM52gi+vrCdR4TKsIsv3b3u4=)